# The window or a window?

Tags: meaning, articles

The articles are confusing, look at these two sentences and tell me is there a difference in their meaning.

Assume ( a total of 5 windows in this case)

> 1a) My ball hit the window of our principal's office.
>
> 1b) My ball hit a window of our principal's office.

Both of these sentences are providing the same meaning then what exactly are "a" and "the" conveying?

Comment: Sentence 1b doesn't sound natural to me - given the office has five windows I think "...hit one of the windows..." would feel more natural. Also I would say "the principal" not "our principal". Still I think most people would interpret both of your sentences the same way, but that doesn't mean that "the" and "a" are interchangeable or have the same meaning in other contexts.

Comment: There is a difference in their meaning.

Comment: @Lawrence Could you please explain, no matter how minor it is, please explain the difference.

Comment: "The" window implies the *only window. Your principal is in an office that has one window and the ball hit it. "A" window implies that the office has multiple windows and the ball hit one of them. But the sentence would sound more natural in that case if you said "My ball hit one of the windows of the principal's office".

Comment: @YevgenySimkin: According to formal grammar, t*he window* may theoretically imply that it is the only window. In the actual language of native speakers, it doesn't.

Comment: @Peter Shor  then what does it imply?

Comment: @PeterShor as a native speaker who wields this "actual language" as well as most, I find your comment bewildering. Further as a professor of math, one might imagine that you would be fond of "formal" things (grammar amongst them). Look again at the question and ask yourself: "What did I add with my comment that is in any way helpful?".
Jason Bassford tackles the nuanced answer beautifully. My comment was -  just that - a comment. You chimed in to "correct" me by saying I'm technically right but woe unto those sad foreigners who would like to know just how "sort of" right I am.
Weird.

Comment: @YevgenySimkin "The" window will not always imply there is only a single window is what Peter meant to say, ig.

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws - There's no reason to read the tea leaves of what he meant to say. Of course "The window" doesn't `always` mean there is a single window. The window is not the door or the wall or my head. But without additional context (and your question lacks additional context), it does convey precisely the implication that it's the only window present. It's THE window.

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws it should be noted that your example sentence is awkward and a native English speaker is unlikely to utter it in either variation. But try out "An asteroid hit Jupiter." vs. "The asteroid hit Jupiter". The first is a fully formed idea. It can be followed by "The End".
The second needs more exposition about *what asteroid it was; otherwise you're leaving this info unstated and the reader is left wondering. `The` describes something specific. `A/an` describe something more generally.

Comment: @Yevegeny: If you look at [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+out+the+window%2C+look+out+a+window&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20out%20the%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20out%20a%20window%3B%2Cc0), native speakers say "look out the window" 30 times more frequently than "look out a window." You surely can't believe that only 3% of native English speakers live in rooms with only one window. So "the window" does not ***always*** imply "the only window", even when there's no context.

Comment: @Yevgeny: Similarly, if somebody says "he took me by the hand" ([see Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took+me+by+the+hand%2C+took+me+by+a+hand&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctook%20me%20by%20the%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20me%20by%20a%20hand%3B%2Cc0)) it doesn't mean the speaker only has one hand. There are exceptions to the rule: "the" means unique, and sometimes "the window" is one of them.

Comment: @Yevgeny: I do agree that with the OP's example, most native speakers would not use 1a if there was more than one window (I'm not convinced that all of them would), so my comment was indeed unhelpful.

Comment: @PeterShor I may have been too harsh (sorry) but I think you are fixating on the "only" as opposed to the "specific" which is what `the` generally implies. And again - I never said "always" - in language there is no "always". But this is a pretty straight forward explanation for how `a` and `the` differ in the context of a thrown ball and a/the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two sentences really comes down to context.

If there have been no preceding sentences, and there are no following sentences, then the meaning is essentially the same.

But if there *is* other information conveyed by another sentence, then there can be a significant difference between the use of the definite article and the indefinite article in the single sentence.

---

### The definite article

The use of the definite article calls out something specific.

Normally, the specificity of the thing is explicit:

> I hit the **red** ball.

The inference is that there is more than one ball, and only one of them is red.

---

But, sometimes, the specificity doesn't need to be explicit.

For instance, a book can start off with the use of the definite article in the following way:

> **The** man was walking down the street.

But which man was it? The man walking down the street.

But what if there were several men walking down the street? It's the man being discussed by **the narrative of the story**.

This man is only just being **introduced**, and will be discussed in greater length in the sentences that *follow*.

In short, the context of specificity need not be not limited to a single sentence, but can apply to the entire paragraph, chapter, or book.

If only that single sentence were given, it would be strange. But, often, it's not the only sentence given about the subject. The resolution of specificity is suspended until later on:

> **The** man was walking down the street. He was **tall**, **wore a hat**, and **walked with a limp.**

The second sentence follows up and gives the specificity that had been lacking in the first sentence. It was **that** man, as opposed to any others that might have been walking down the street with him.

---

The same is true of the ball with the window:

> My ball hit **the** window of our principal's office.

But which window was it? The window that my ball hit.

But what if there were several windows?

As in the other example, the resolution of specificity can be resolved in a following sentence:

> My ball hit **the** window of our principal's office. It was **the same window that had been broken last week**.

There is a slight let down of expectation if **the window** is *not* narrowed down further in a subsequent sentence, because we normally expect there to be something more. However, even if that's not the case, we can still picture some window in general being hit.

---

If there *is* no further resolution of specificity, and the only mention of the window is in the single sentence, *and* it's been made clear that the principal's office has more than one window, then it's more normal to phrase it differently:

> My ball hit **one of the windows** of our principal's office.

---

Note that if nothing has ever been said about how many windows there are, and no further mention is made in later sentences about this, then the use of the definite article without any qualification will have the reader infer there only is a single window.

---

### The indefinite article

> My ball hit **a** window of our principal's office.

Without any further qualification, this says exactly the same thing as the following:

> My ball hit **one of the windows** of our principal's office.

The indefinite article on its own just says that there is more than one window. *Which* of the several windows was hit need not be explained, although it often is.

Whether you use **a** or **one of the** is a matter of style and personal preference. In this particular sentence, it's likely that **one of the** is more common, but that doesn't mean that **a** is actually wrong.

---

Note that the same book as before could also start in this way:

> **A** man was walking down the street. He was **tall**, **wore a hat**, and **walked with a limp.**

What's the difference? With the use of the definite article, there's a very subtle nuance that you're calling out a *particular* man from the first sentence.

But with the indefinite article, even though you later talk about a particular man, it starts off as if it's referring to a man of no particular importance. It only becomes clear that the man has a particular importance in the second sentence.

It's probably more common to use the indefinite article in this case. But there is certainly a writing style that deliberately uses the definite article in order to put additional emphasis on the special nature of the subject from the start.

Comment: I have another question regarding articles which is slightly connected to the gist of my main question on this thread(sorry for asking this here). When one says "I have a right to punish you", does this mean that the speaker has more than 1 right to punish? And does always "a" mean that there is more than one when followed by relative clauses or say prepositional clauses?

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws If I say *I'm holding a ball in my hand*, it doesn't mean that I'm holding more than one. In fact, it normally means that there is only one ball in my hand. The use of *a* is about the nonspecific nature of the ball—it could be any ball at all. But it's also true that there is more than one ball in the world. The same is true about *a right to punish you*. No doubt there exist many different rights that involve punishment. So, it's not about the *speaker* having more rights, but just the speaker being in the position of having one of them at the moment.